# How delete part of SVN history

Tags: svn

I want to delete part of revisions from my SVN. For example:

```
LastID  Last commit
8000    Another commit
7890    First interesting commit 
2000    Some old commit
1000    Some old commit
FirstID Initial commit
```

I want to achieve:

```
LastID  Last commit
SomeID  Another commit
FirstID First interesting commit
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/):

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r7890:LastID > svn.dump
svnadmin create /path/to/new/repo
svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo < svn.dump
```

**Note**: revision numbers in new repo will change comparing to the old repo, so your old revision 7890 now will become revision 1.

Comment: Thanks for respond. I already fount this solution on this webside:
http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/

This take a lot of time to copy SVN base (about 90 hours in my case). There is no other, quicker way?